# Python: Matplotlib is connecting random points

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

matplotlib is connecting random points and I don't know why. The dataframe consists of a Datatimeindex, and just two number columns:

[image: Plot]

If I do this graph with the SAME data in Excel the graph is correct:

[image: correct Plot]

This is the code that I use:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.plot(pred_true_comp.index,pred_true_comp["predictions"], color=  "#43a2ca", label="Predictions")

plt.plot(pred_true_comp.index,pred_true_comp["true_values"], color=  "#a8ddb5", label="True Values")

plt.legend(loc = "upper right",bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))

plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.1))
plt.axhline(y=0.5, color = "red", label = "Critical Value")
plt.title("US Predictions vs. True Values " + "(" + kernel + " " + "kernel" + "), " + Name)

#plt.savefig("US_Results/" + Model_name + "Prediction" + ".png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you show the correct plot?

Comment: I added the correct plot

Comment: Did you try to sort the dataframe on its index?

Comment: I found the mistake, it was in the creation of the Dataframe earlier. I ran a loop and overwrote the index. But my overwriting process was shorter than the lenght of the index and then some entries were wrong in the index. Thank you anyway! :) The sorting of the DataFrame would also have solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake, it was in a loop earlier. Thank you all anyway.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).